# open google play store on image click in android

Tags: android, image, click

I have a about us page in android and there is a google play store image. On click of that image i want to open google play store
Can any1 help me about how to do this thing? XML file and java class attached below. I am a newbie in android so please tell about all the changes to be made in all the files. Thanks

```
about us xml file





<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/share_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dividerMargin">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dummyText"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/playstoreImg"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/google_play" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/appstoreImg"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ios_app_store" />



        </LinearLayout>
```

About us java file

```
    public class AboutUs extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_us);

        setBackBtnVisibility(true);
        setTitle(getString(R.string.by_mobi));
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your XML Layout:

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/appstoreImg"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ios_app_store"
            android:onClick="openGooglePlay" />
```

In your activity / java file add this method:

```
public void openGooglePlay(View v) {
    Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.vending");
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("com.android.vending", "com.google.android.finsky.activities.LaunchUrlHandlerActivity"); 

    launchIntent.setComponent(comp);

    // only line you need to edit is this next one
    launchIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=your.package.name")); // or "market://details?id=your.app.id"

    startActivity(launchIntent);
}
```

Comment: ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("com.android.vending", "com.google.android.finsky.activities.LaunchUrlHandlerActivity"); // package name and activity (which activity name)

Comment: @girish The one listed in my answer :) The only line you need to edit is this one: launchIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=your.package.name"));

Answer (score -1):

You can use this on Image click:

```
Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="
                                    + getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
```